# Fragment not attached to Activity NewPermissionsRequest facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-fragments

I am working on my first android app and am trying to request addtional publish_actions permissions.  Following the documentation I am request them only when needed.

However I am receiving this error:

```
02-19 16:19:19.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12456): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 16:19:19.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12456): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MainFragment{40d66eb0} not attached to Activity
02-19 16:19:19.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12456):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:889)
02-19 16:19:19.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12456):    at com.facebook.Session$AuthorizationRequest$2.startActivityForResult(Session.java:1920)
02-19 16:19:19.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12456):    at com.facebook.Session.tryLoginActivity(Session.java:1409)
02-19 16:19:19.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12456):    at com.facebook.Session.authorize(Session.java:1159)
02-19 16:19:19.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12456):    at com.facebook.Session.requestNewPermissions(Session.java:1264)
02-19 16:19:19.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12456):    at com.facebook.Session.requestNewPublishPermissions(Session.java:595)
02-19 16:19:19.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12456):    at com.cp1.ActivityRestaurantDetails$5$2.onClick(ActivityRestaurantDetails.java:332)
02-19 16:19:19.544: E/AndroidRuntime(12456):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3538)
```

I've been reading on here about fragments but I can't seem to figure this out.  Here is the code that is calling my fragment

ActivityRestaurantDetails.java

```
btn_facebook.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

                            if (session != null) {

                                // Check for publish permissions
                                List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();


                                String test = "nothing";
                                if (!isSubsetOf(SplashScreen.PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                                    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                                              .NewPermissionsRequest(mainFragment, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
                                            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);

                                }
                            }

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getParent(), ActivitySharing.class);

                            intent.putExtra("parent_class", "ActivityRestaurantDetails");
                            intent.putExtra("share_type","facebook");

                            TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();
                            parentActivity.startChildActivity("ActivitySharing", intent);
                        }
                    });
```

Here is my fragment code...
MainFragment.java

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback); 
         uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }






    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };


    public void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
     {
        if (state.isOpened()) 
        {
            Log.i("facebook", "Logged in...");
            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) 
                {

                    if(SplashScreen.fb_login==false){
                        if(user!=null)
                        {
                          SplashScreen.fb_login=true;

                          SplashScreen.first_name=user.getFirstName()+"";
                          SplashScreen.last_name=user.getLastName()+"";
                          SplashScreen.fb_id=user.getId()+"";
                          SplashScreen.birthday=user.getBirthday()+"";
                          SplashScreen.fb_page=user.getLink()+"";
                          SplashScreen.email=user.asMap().get("email") + "";
                          SplashScreen.username=user.asMap().get("email") + "";
                          SplashScreen.gender=user.asMap().get("gender") + "";
                          SplashScreen.timezone=user.asMap().get("timezone") + "";


                          if(SplashScreen.fb_status.equals("login")){
                              SplashScreen.AL.Login();
                          }else if(SplashScreen.fb_status.equals("logout")){


                          }else if(SplashScreen.fb_status.equals("register")){
                              SplashScreen.AR.getCode();

                          }


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            String test=("its null");
                            test=(response.getError().getErrorMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).executeAsync();

        } 
        else if (state.isClosed()) 
        {
            Log.i("facebook", "Logged out...");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
        // session is not null, the session state change notification
        // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null &&
               (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }

        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

}
```

Any idea how to fix this issue? I have the onActivityResult method set in ActivityRestaurantDetails.

Comment: where is btn_facebook? If it's a different activity, then you should use that in your new permission request rather than the MainFragment. You also shouldn't start a child activity while the new permissions request is happening, since the SDK will be starting another activity to do the SSO.

Comment: Can you add the code where you instantiate the fragment within the activity?